# Java: ZipFile using Path

Tags: java, nio, nio2, jimfs

I have a `Path` to zip file on virtual filesystem (jimfs) and I need to open this zip file using `ZipFile`.

But there is no constructor in `ZipFile` to get `Path` as argument, only `File`.

However, I can't create from my `Path` a `File` (path.toFile()) because I get `UnsupportedOperationException`. How can I open my zip file with `ZipFile`? Or maybe there are other ways of working with zip files which are not on default filesystem?

Comment: Use `ZipFile(String)` instead?

Comment: @Yassin Hajaj I get `FileNotFoundException` because it finds the file on default file system, but not on virtual one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ZipFile` class is limited to files in the file-system.

An alternative would be to use `ZipInputStream` instead. Create an `InputStream` from your `Path` using

```
Path path = ...
InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path, openOptions)
```

and the use the `InputStream` to create an `ZipInputStream`. This way should work as expected:

```
ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in)
```

So the recommended way to use it is:

```
try (ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(path))) {
    // do something with the ZipInputStream
}
```

Note that decompressing certain ZIP files using `ZipInputStream` [will fail because of their ZIP structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47208272/150978). This is a technical limitation of the ZIP format and can't be solved. In such cases you have to create a temporary file in file-system or memory and use a different ZIP class like `ZipFile`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved exactly the same problem (I need to unpack zip file stored on JimFS filesystem)

There is a problem with Robert's response. `ZipFile` and `ZipInputStream` similar, but not equal. One of big disadvantage of ZipInputStream - it's doesn't fail in case of wrong or damaged zip file. It just return null on first `nextEntry` call. For example following test will pass without errors

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testZip() {
        val randomBytes = Random.nextBytes(1000)

        ZipInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(randomBytes)).use { zis ->
            var zipEntry = zis.nextEntry
            while (zipEntry != null) {
                println(zipEntry.name)
                zipEntry = zis.nextEntry
            }
        }
    }
```

So, if in case of zip files obtained from user input or by unstable network, there isn't any chance to check zip using `ZipInputStream`. The only option here - to use Java's `FileSystems`. The following test will fail with error `zip END header not found`. With correct zip file newFileSystem works fine, of course.

```
    @Test
    fun testZipFS() {
        val randomBytes = Random.nextBytes(1000)

        val tmpFile = Files.createTempFile(Path.of("/tmp"), "tmp", ".zip")
        Files.write(tmpFile, randomBytes)

        val zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(srcZip, null)

        val zipRoot = zipFs.rootDirectories.single()
        Files.walk(zipRoot).forEach { p ->
            println(p.absolutePathString())
        }
    }
```