# Android ZipInputStream: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor

Tags: java, android, zip, uri

On my android device, I need to extract a file (an xapk, that is a plain zip archive as far as I know) that I get from a content uri.
I'm creating the ZipInputStream using this line of code:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(zipUri));
```

And then I try to read the first entry of the archive with:

```
ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry()
```

The problem is that I get this exception:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT
>   descriptor

I'm 100% sure that there is no 0bytes files in the archive, and I can extract the same archive with other utilities (RAR, unzip etc) in my device.

If I use a ZipFile with an hard coded path (so no content uri involved), I can extract the same archive without problems, so the issue is related to ZipInputStream with an uri. On the other hand, I can't use a ZipFile here because it doesn't support content uris.

Comment: Are you sure that you have read access to the content? For example, if you pass the `Uri` from an activity (where perhaps you got it) to a service (where perhaps you have the `ZipInputStream`), you need to include `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent` used to start the service, even though the activity and service are both part of your app. Beyond that, have you tried any other ZIP-style archive? Worst-case scenario, you might need to copy the content bytes to some file that you control, use that file with `ZipFile`, then delete that file when you no longer need it.

Comment: Yeah, I've read access to the content. This error happens only when I try to unzip the XAPK file. I can unzip any other file (zip, apk etc) with the same code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately the only answer is currently:

Don't process ZIP files in streaming mode like `ZipInputStream` does. It seems like all currently available ZIP processing components like `ZipInputStream` from the JRE and `ZipArchiveInputStream` from [Apache commons-compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) can not handle such ZIP files.

There is a very good description of the problem on the apache commons-compress help page:

> ZIP archives know a feature called the data descriptor which is a way
> to store an entry's length after the entry's data. This can only work
> reliably if the size information can be taken from the central
> directory or the data itself can signal it is complete, which is true
> for data that is compressed using the DEFLATED compression algorithm.
>
> ZipFile has access to the central directory and can extract entries
> using the data descriptor reliably. The same is true for
> ZipArchiveInputStream as long as the entry is DEFLATED. For STORED
> entries ZipArchiveInputStream can try to read ahead until it finds the
> next entry, but this approach is not safe and has to be enabled by a
> constructor argument explicitly.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html

## Solution

The only possibility to avoid this problem is to use `ZipFile`, however the [`ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) implementation for the JRE requires a real file, therefore you may have to save to data to a temporary file.

Or if you use instead [`ZipFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html) from Apache commons-compress and you already have the ZIP file completely in-memory you can avoid saving it to a temporary file using `ZipFile.Builder().setByteArray(byteArray).get()` instead.

#### Kotlin

Example code using in-memory ZipFile of Apache Common Compress v1.26 or newer:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream().use { byteArrayOutputStream ->
    inputStream.copyTo(byteArrayOutputStream)
    ZipFile.Buider().setByteArray(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()).get().use {
        for (entry in it.entries) {
            it.getInputStream(entry).copyTo(someOutputStream)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Java

Example code using in-memory ZipFile of Apache Common Compress v1.26 or newer:

```java
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.*;

ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] data = inputStream.readAllBytes();

Builder zipFileBuilder = new ZipFile.Builder().setByteArray(data);
try (ZipFile zipFile = zipFileBuilder.get()) {
    Enumeration<ZipArchiveEntry> it = zipFile.getEntries();
    while (it.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = it.nextElement();
        zipFile.getInputStream(entry).transferTo(someOutputStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using commons-compress

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a snippet

```
public void unzip(File zipFile, File destDir) throws IOException, ArchiveException {
       String destDirectory = destDir.getAbsolutePath();

       try (ArchiveInputStream i = new ZipArchiveInputStream(new 
          FileInputStream(zipFile), "UTF-8", false, true)) {
          ArchiveEntry entry = null;
          while ((entry = i.getNextEntry()) != null) {
             if (!i.canReadEntryData(entry)) {
                System.out.println("Can't read entry: " + entry);
                continue;
             }
             String name = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
             File f = new File(name);
             if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                if (!f.isDirectory() && !f.mkdirs()) {
                   throw new IOException("failed to create directory " + f);
                }
             } else {
                File parent = f.getParentFile();
                if (!parent.isDirectory() && !parent.mkdirs()) {
                   throw new IOException("failed to create directory " + parent);
                }
                try (OutputStream o = Files.newOutputStream(f.toPath())) {
                   IOUtils.copy(i, o);
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately apache commons-compress also throws an Exception on `getNextEntry()`, therefore the call to `canReadEntryData()` does not help here: `UnsupportedZipFeatureException: unsupported feature data descriptor used in entry ...`